# How to find a span (has other html elements) with specific text

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to find the list item based on the contents in the span.

I tried using //li/a[contains(., 'Business')]

It is working for unique items, But here, it gives a list because it is matching more than one.

I want to ignore the inner span and only focus on the span text to identify the li. How can i achieve it?

```
<li style="display: list-item;">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="avoidwrap">
            <span class="icomoon-cube3">
            </span> 
            Business
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="display: list-item;">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="avoidwrap">
            <span class="icomoon-cube3">
            </span> 
            Business Something
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: i don't see any difference in structures of that two `li`

Comment: Structure are same, But the text in spans are different. 'Business' and 'Business Something'

Comment: `//li/a/span[normalize-space(.)='Business'] ` ?

Comment: Thanks splash58, your xpath code worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by splash58 in comments worked,

```
//li/a/span[normalize-space(.)='Business']
```